# Proving $k$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ iff $k\,|\gcd(a,b)$ -- converse

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm currently trying to solve the converse of this statement is true after proving the normal version is true. If $k$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, then $k \,| \gcd(a, b)$

So far I know the converse states that if $k \,| \gcd(a, b)$ then $k$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Can anyone help me out and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start you off. Let $d = \text{gcd}(a,b)$. Then by definition $d|a$ and $d|b$. Now suppose $k|d$. Can you use what you know about division to prove the result?

Comment: Hold on... which way are you trying to prove?

Comment: if k|d and ax+by=d then k|ax+by. Is that in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry - I should clarify. Both directions are true. Which was the direction that you wanted help with? I was assuming that you were stuck trying to prove that if $k|\text{gcd}(a,b)$, then $k|a$ and $k|b$

Comment: yes your assumption was correct

Comment: Ah OK. If I were to tell you that $x|y$ and $y|z$, what can you tell me about $x$ and $z$? Then have a reread of what I wrote. This way round doesn't require Bézout's theorem

Comment: by transitivity of division you can say that k|a and k|b?